# Function for measuring change compared to year zero

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that has a column for "low", "mid", and "high" and a column for year (either 2019, 2020, or 2021) with averages following. I want to find change by level compared to the first year (2019) (aka 2020-2019 and 2021-2020). I was using the function: df %>% group_by(level) %>% arrange(year) %>% mutate(growth_rate = average / lag(average)). However, using this function, 2021 is compared to 2020. Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing?

| level | year | average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Low | 2019 | 1300 |
| Mid | 2019 | 2065 |
| High | 2019 | 2194 |
| Low | 2020 | 2966 |
| Mid | 2020 | 4723 |
| High | 2020 | 5915 |
| Low | 2021 | 4049 |
| Mid | 2021 | 5915 |
| High | 2021 | 5978 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df %>%
   group_by(level) %>% 
   arrange(year) %>% 
   mutate(growth_rate = average / first(average))
```

Also, can you type `dput(<your data here>)` in the console and paste that into your question? It will help others to copy and paste the data frame you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

We may do this directly with `which.min` i.e. after grouping by 'level', divide the 'average' by the 'average' value on the `min`imum 'year'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(level) %>%
    mutate(growth_rate = average/average[which.min(year)])
```